# user access token, wrong format

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm going to explain my code:

A) user log's in to my app and gives permission for publish_stream and user_photos

B) the app makes an API call and gets all the user's albums in a dropdownlist

C) the user chooses a picture by browsing his computer, using the multipart/form-data as suggested by Facebook

D) the user chooses an album form the dropdownlist and submits the form

E) then facebook redirects the user to a page with this URL:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[album-idd]/photos`

and instead of displaying the ID of the newly uploaded picture(like they say in the developer documentation), facebook displays this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

But when i try to get the access token it's format is:

```
AAADnKCRahQQBANVoNY3LHLVjYpiYzEm2h7vZAbXxDz29nvJTW9m3gmlgu1JOwdbqYHMa8jQyTnqcS1LU0RuMW2GqBs2OnOowZCinK4CDDD87snZAYQF
```

instead of the format aaa|bbb|ccc. What am i doing wrong? and do i get the right access token? or is this a wrong one?

Comment: The encrypted access token format should work exactly the same as the old tokens for all API calls (the XMPP login is one exception) - please edit your question to explain the problem you're having - it's really not clear from the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has changed the acess token format. What you are getting is the correct token. Check that your token is working by visiting this link:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={access_token from your question}

Also, check out the following links to get an idea of what has changed:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/555/

If you have any problems using the new access token, please elaborate them a bit further.

Comment: Ok, thank you, my access token clearly works, because i get the right info. But why do i still get this error? when the user submits the form i say:
form.action("http://graph.facebook.com/"+albumid+"/photos"
do i have to do more than that? no, i think? My server were my project is running does not have SSL yet, could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you including the access token as a parameter in the POST request?

Comment: Not in the post request no, because as documented in the javascript SDK, you don't need to, but another solution is to give the access_token with your url:
https://graph.facebook.com/+albumid+/photos?access_token=xxxxxx
the solution looks very easy, but it wasn't :p thanks for your time folks!